# Highlight Polygon coordinates using OpenLayers 4

Tags: polygon, javascript, openlayers

Is it possible to highlight all the boundary coordinates of a polygon in OpenLayers 4 JavaScript API as shown in the image .[image: Polygon coordinates highlighted in a leafletjs example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to draw the vertices in addition to the feature itself in OpenLayers.  See this [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/polygon-styles.html).

Here's a snippet from that example:

```
  var styles = [
    /* We are using two different styles for the polygons:
     *  - The first style is for the polygons themselves.
     *  - The second style is to draw the vertices of the polygons.
     *    In a custom `geometry` function the vertices of a polygon are
     *    returned as `MultiPoint` geometry, which will be used to render
     *    the style.
     */
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'blue',
        width: 3
      }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
      })
    }),
    new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'orange'
        })
      }),
      geometry: function(feature) {
        // return the coordinates of the first ring of the polygon
        var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0];
        return new ol.geom.MultiPoint(coordinates);
      }
    })
  ];
```